# argparse.print_help() ArgumentParser message string

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am writing a slack bot, and I am using `argsparse` to parse the arguments sent into the slackbot, but I am trying to figure out how to get the help message string so I can send it back to the user via the slack bot.

I know that `ArgumentParser` has a `print_help()` method, but that is printed via console and I need a way to get that string.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that there's a method called format_help() that generates that help string